# Symfony 3 and Doctrine Link Table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

My goal is to create Term Tables for translations in Symfony3 and Doctrine.

- One Table (TERMS) should contain a Primary Key Id and the Term.
- The second Table (TermLink) should contain the Link between Term and its translation which is also a Term, like: TermId | TranslationId - **Those are foreign keys of the of the same primary key - Term ID Field**.
  There are multiple approaches to achieve this that are described: [Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities) but none of them fits my needs.

Here are my actual Entities that I would like to implement:

Term Table:

```
/**
* Translation Term
*
* @ORM\Table(name="translation_term")
* @ORM\Entity‚
*/
class TranslTerm
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="term_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $termId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="term", type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $term;
}
```

Link Table:

```
/**
 * Translation Link - One To Many/JoinTable -
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="translation_link")
 * @ORM\Entity‚
 */
class TranslLink
{
    private $id;
    private $termId;
    private $translationId;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly look here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html OR https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Secondly here's something that should be a good start:

```
class TranslLink
{
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Terms", mappedBy="trans_link")
     */
    private $termId;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Translations", mappedBy="trans_link")
     */
    private $translationId;
}
```

PUBLIC HEALTH WARNING about the above:

straight outta the top of my head, will not work out the box and might be off. But the principle of what you want should be able to be derived from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. TargetEntity in both of the termId and translationId is the Terms Entity (table). Also the Terms table has to include OneToMany relation regarding TranslLink?